# Iphone/ipad app system stats

Tags: objective-c, ios

I would like to see what my app is doing with system resource while users are using it. Ideally on the view I can print real time CPU and Ram stats and then have the user report back to me the max or min etc.. of these values. My feeling is that this will help us test the nuances of some advanced UI things.

Any ideas on how to make this happen?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to get that information about your App from the iPhone SDK. It shows you this info in Instruments but that won't be available on your App.